# rotate plane so its normal is the same direction as another plane's normal

Tags: java, math, opengl, 3d

My problem is that I have a surface in world space (three 3D points) that I want to rotate so that the resulting normal of those three points will be the same as another plane's normal, while maintaining the original surface's 'triangular shape'.

If the "destination" plane has a normal of (0, 0, 1) and a point on that plane is (0, 0, 0), and the "source" points are [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5] [-0.5, -0.5, 0.5] [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5], what calculation must I make to rotate those points so that the surface normal becomes (0, 0, 1)?

I have tried simply 'projecting' the "source" points to the "destination" plane using the following method "projectPointToPlane":

```
public static Vector3f projectPointToPlane(Vector3f point, Vector3f planePoint, Vector3f planeNormal)
{
    float dot = EEngineUtils.getDotProduct(EEngineUtils.getProjectionVector(point, planePoint), planeNormal);
    return new Vector3f(point.getX()+planeNormal.getX()*-dot, point.getY()+planeNormal.getY()*-dot, point.getZ()+planeNormal.getZ()*-dot);
}

public static Vector3f getProjectionVector(Vector3f to, Vector3f from)
{
    return new Vector3f(to.getX()-from.getX(), to.getY()-from.getY(), to.getZ()-from.getZ());
}

public static float getDotProduct(Vector3f v1, Vector3f v2)
{
    return (v1.getX()*v2.getX())+(v1.getY()*v2.getY())+(v1.getZ()*v2.getZ());
}
```

However I did not get the results I was hoping for.
For example, here are the source points:

Vector3f[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5] | Vector3f[-0.5, -0.5, 0.5] | Vector3f[-0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

here are the resulting points of the projection:

Vector3f[-0.5, -0.5, 0.0] | Vector3f[-0.5, -0.5, 0.0] | Vector3f[-0.5, 0.5, 0.0]

The first two resulting points are the same, which is not what I wanted. I wanted the shape of the resulting 'triangle' to be the same (in this case, a right-angled triangle).
My assumption is that 'projection' isn't what I need and that what I really need is some kind of "rotation", however I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I thought about finding the angle between the two surface normals and rotating the points by that angle, but I wouldn't know what 'axis' vector to use for the rotation.
Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I'm being too vague.

Note I'm using the LWJGL API in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Use cross products. The current normal to your triangle is a cross product of vectors build on its vertexes (after normalization). The axis of rotation is a cross product of the normal to the plane (0,0,1) and the normal of the triangle. The sinus of the rotation angle is the length of the last cross-product (assumed that the normals are normalized, i.e. the normals are unit vectors).

In your case:
Triangle A:[-.5,-.5,-.5] B:[-.5,-.5,.5] C:[-.5,.5,.5]

Vectors that forms this triangle

AB: [-.5,-.5,.5]-[-.5,-.5,-.5]=[0,0,1]

AC: [-.5,.5,.5]-[-.5,-.5,-.5]=[0,1,1]

Cross product: AB x AC =[-1,0,0], this is already normalized this is a normal to ABC triangle

Rotation axis: [-1,0,0] x [0,0,1]=[0,1,0]

Sinus of rotation angle is 1, i.e. angle is 90 degrees.

Cosinus of rotation angle is a scalar product of normal vectors
[-1,0,0] . [0,0,1]=0, this also gives 90 degree.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a look-at operation, though with the added complication that neither of the normals are necessarily pointing down one of your axes.

So you could form two matrices, which would orient the two planes along a common axis, and then multiply one by the inverse of the other (and in this form, the inverse is just the transpose, so it would be trivial).

A look-at matrix is easy to calculate, using only a couple of cross-products and some normalisation.

(if your 'destination' plane is *actually* oriented such that its normal is an axis, just directly build the look-at matrix).